# Inet framework getting time

Tags: omnet++, inet, wireless

I'm using the wireless example, and i want get the simulation time and save in parameter for calculate the time the packet arrival and the packet send. Have anyone solution for these?

Answer (score 0):

There is a statistics for this automatically collected in application models (i.e. like BasicUdpApp etc.). It's called endToEndDelay.

The proper way to do this (and this what is already done in INET) is that you during packet creation you should add a TAG to the sent packet which contains a simtime_t variable and put the actual simtime there and then read the same TAG when the packet arrives and calculate the difference. Putting values into the "parameters" of a message would NOT work as the packets could be fragmented/defragmented in the network so their identity is not kept and the attached parameters are destroyed.

But again, this is already present in INET 4.2